# Adobe Audition CS6 vs Syntrillium Cool Edit Pro 2.1 - editing wave

Tags: audio-editing

In Cool Edit Pro when a waveform is in maximum zoom level, it is possible to drag an audio sample vertically, or "Editing Sample Directly" by left clicking on an audio sample. How can I achieve the same in Audition ?

```
below : `Before drag (Cool Edit Pro)`
```

[image]

```
below : `After drag (Cool Edit Pro)`
```

[image]

```
below : `After left click on audio sample (Cool Edit Pro)`
```

[image]

```
below : `Can not drag (Audition CS6)`
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Audition doesn't offer this function.   However many times this question is bumped, I'm afraid this remains the answer!

Comment: what a pity ! how is it even possible to take an application, downgrade it, and name the procedure an upgrade ?

Comment: Standard practice by Apple :-)

Comment: You can bump this question all you like, the answer remains the same.  Audition doesn't have this function.

Comment: Bumped again, I see!   The answer still remains the same.

Comment: Laurence, this gets “auto-bumped” as a question without upvoted answers. I’ll give you a +1 to stop it being bumped. If the OP is desperate for more answers he can always put a bounty on the question!

Answer (score 0):

Zoom in, then select via the mouse the desired area. A "db" small window will popup and there you can select how many db you want to amplify or decrease the sample.

[image]

Comment: I'm looking for the same functionality in Audition as it is in Cool Edit Pro. I need to input exact values for given samples. Also, in case when sample value is zero ( point is exactly in the middle ), then amplify does not move anything because there is nothing to amplify..